# How to add kivymd MDCheckBox to kv RecycleView with a Label that shows what the checkbox stands for?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm currently working on an application where you can store your plans and get notifications using *Python Kivy and KivyMD*, but I have a problem with the *MDCheckbox*. All current plans are meant to be displayed on the Menu Window, in this format: **PlanText** *(represented by an MDLabel)* and **IsDone** *(represented by an MDCheckbox)*. However, when the app is running, there is nothing, but the checkboxes - *no plan texts whatsoever*: [Screenshot of the running app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S6rG.png)

**A bit of my Python code:**

```
class PlansToDisplay(RecycleView):
    """This class is used to display user's current plans"""

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    @property
    def data(self):
        # If a user has already planned something, this function returns a list
        # of dicts containing plan texts. If not, it just returns an empty list.
        
        # -> For the record, -plan- is a tuple represented in
        # the following format: (PlanText, PlanPriority, IsDone)

        if current_day in STORAGE.to_dict.keys():
            return [{"text": str(plan[0])} for plan in STORAGE.to_dict[current_day]]
        return []
```

**A bit of my KV code:**

```
<MyButton@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    
    # Is supposed to contain a plan text
    MDLabel:
        size_hint: .8, None
    
    # Is meant for keeping track of whether the 
    # user's finished the plan or not.
    MDCheckbox:
        size_hint: .2, None


<PlansToDisplay>:
    viewclass: "MyButton"
    grid: grid

    RecycleGridLayout:
        id: grid
        orientation: 'vertical'

        cols: 1
        size_hint: 1, None
        default_size: None, None
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.minimum_height
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: What does `print(self.data)` show in the `PlansToDisplay` instance?

Comment: It shows a list of dictionaries, each containing a key 'text' with the value - 'plantext'. Something like, [{"text": "brush your teeth"}, {"text": "clean your face"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to add a `text` property to your `MyButton` class, something like this:

```
<MyButton@GridLayout>:
    cols: 2
    text: ''
    
    # Is supposed to contain a plan text
    MDLabel:
        size_hint: .8, None
        text: root.text
    
    # Is meant for keeping track of whether the 
    # user's finished the plan or not.
    MDCheckbox:
        size_hint: .2, None
```

You will likely need to do something similar for the `MDCheckBox`.

Comment: The thing is that the program is supposed to add the text from the ```self.data```, which means that you can hardly access it for EACH button that's supposed to be displayed on the Screen

Comment: Wow, I don't know how it happened, but this helped.... Thank you very much!

Comment: The `RecycleView` sets attributes of the `viewclass` (in this case the `MyButton`) using the data dictionary. So, if you want that attribute to be used as the `text` of the `MDLabel`, you must arrange for that to happen.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Thx for extra explanation :)